# macOS react-native This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon

Tags: java, android, react-native, macos, gradle

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58764088/error-unable-to-start-the-daemon-process-this-problem-might-be-caused-by-incor) but couldn't fix the problem.

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xms512M -Xmx4g -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g -Dkotlin.daemon.jvm.options="-Xmx1g"
```

[image]

```
Welcome to Gradle 8.1.1!

Here are the highlights of this release:
 - Stable configuration cache
 - Experimental Kotlin DSL assignment syntax
 - Building with Java 20

For more details see https://docs.gradle.org/8.1.1/release-notes.html


------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 8.1.1
------------------------------------------------------------

Build time:   2023-04-21 12:31:26 UTC
Revision:     1cf537a851c635c364a4214885f8b9798051175b

Kotlin:       1.8.10
Groovy:       3.0.15
Ant:          Apache Ant(TM) version 1.10.11 compiled on July 10 2021
JVM:          17.0.7 (Homebrew 17.0.7+0)
OS:           Mac OS X 13.2.1 x86_64
```

Error:

```
yarn run v1.22.4
$ react-native run-android
info JS server already running.

info  Tip: Make sure that you have set up your development environment correctly, by running react-native doctor. To read more about doctor command visit: https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/blob/main/packages/cli-doctor/README.md#doctor 


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms512M -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IT -Duser.language=it -Duser.variant -cp /Users/userName/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.5.1-all/1ehga6e77gqps5uk2kc5kf1vc/gradle-7.5.1/lib/gradle-launcher-7.5.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.5.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------
Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.
* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
error Failed to install the app. Command failed with exit code 1: ./gradlew tasks FAILURE: Build failed with an exception. * What went wrong:
Unable to start the daemon process.
This problem might be caused by incorrect configuration of the daemon.
For example, an unrecognized jvm option is used.
Please refer to the User Manual chapter on the daemon at https://docs.gradle.org/7.5.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html
Process command line: /Users/userName/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-20.0.1/Contents/Home/bin/java -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=1g --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.lang.invoke=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.prefs/java.util.prefs=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.nio.charset=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.net=ALL-UNNAMED --add-opens java.base/java.util.concurrent.atomic=ALL-UNNAMED -Xms512M -Xmx4g -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Duser.country=IT -Duser.language=it -Duser.variant -cp /Users/userName/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-7.5.1-all/1ehga6e77gqps5uk2kc5kf1vc/gradle-7.5.1/lib/gradle-launcher-7.5.1.jar org.gradle.launcher.daemon.bootstrap.GradleDaemon 7.5.1
Please read the following process output to find out more:
-----------------------

Unrecognized VM option 'MaxPermSize=1024m'
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit. * Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights. * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible Daemon could not be reused, use --status for details.
error Command failed with exit code 1.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

Android studio:

```
Build file '/Users/userName/Desktop/react-native-vision-camera/package/android/build.gradle' line: 63

A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vision-camera'.
> react-native-vision-camera: Failed to find node_modules/ path!

* Try:
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.GradleScriptException: A problem occurred evaluating project ':react-native-vision-camera'.
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:93)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.lambda$apply$0(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:133)
    at org.gradle.configuration.ProjectScriptTarget.addConfiguration(ProjectScriptTarget.java:79)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultScriptPluginFactory$ScriptPluginImpl.apply(DefaultScriptPluginFactory.java:136)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin$1.run(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.lambda$apply$0(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.configuration.internal.DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.apply(DefaultUserCodeApplicationContext.java:44)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationScriptPlugin.apply(BuildOperationScriptPlugin.java:62)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:369)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:42)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.BuildScriptProcessor.execute(BuildScriptProcessor.java:26)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.evaluate(ConfigureActionsProjectEvaluator.java:35)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.lambda$run$0(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:109)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$applyToMutableState$0(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:351)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.lambda$fromMutableState$1(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withReplacedLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.fromMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:374)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.applyToMutableState(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:350)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator$EvaluateProject.run(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:100)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.project.LifecycleProjectEvaluator.evaluate(LifecycleProjectEvaluator.java:72)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:761)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProject.evaluate(DefaultProject.java:152)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.lambda$ensureSelfConfigured$1(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning$9(StateTransitionController.java:196)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.maybeTransitionIfNotCurrentlyTransitioning(StateTransitionController.java:192)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.ProjectLifecycleController.ensureSelfConfigured(ProjectLifecycleController.java:63)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.project.DefaultProjectStateRegistry$ProjectStateImpl.ensureConfigured(DefaultProjectStateRegistry.java:325)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configure(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:33)
    at org.gradle.execution.TaskPathProjectEvaluator.configureHierarchy(TaskPathProjectEvaluator.java:49)
    at org.gradle.configuration.DefaultProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(DefaultProjectsPreparer.java:50)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildTreePreparingProjectsPreparer.java:64)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer$ConfigureBuild.run(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:29)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$1.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:26)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.run(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:68)
    at org.gradle.configuration.BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.prepareProjects(BuildOperationFiringProjectsPreparer.java:40)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.lambda$prepareProjects$3(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$doTransition$12(StateTransitionController.java:236)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:235)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transitionIfNotPreviously$10(StateTransitionController.java:210)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:34)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transitionIfNotPreviously(StateTransitionController.java:206)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.prepareProjects(VintageBuildModelController.java:89)
    at org.gradle.initialization.VintageBuildModelController.getConfiguredModel(VintageBuildModelController.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.lambda$withProjectsConfigured$1(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$notInState$3(StateTransitionController.java:143)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.notInState(StateTransitionController.java:139)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withProjectsConfigured(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:114)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildToolingModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildToolingModelController.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.lambda$locateBuilderForTarget$0(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.DefaultBuildLifecycleController.withToolingModels(DefaultBuildLifecycleController.java:174)
    at org.gradle.internal.build.AbstractBuildState.withToolingModels(AbstractBuildState.java:118)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator$DefaultBuildTreeModelController.locateBuilderForDefaultTarget(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:68)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getTarget(DefaultBuildController.java:157)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.DefaultBuildController.getModel(DefaultBuildController.java:101)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(ParameterAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:39)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.getModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:113)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.getModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:97)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:81)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.UnparameterizedBuildController.findModel(UnparameterizedBuildController.java:66)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.findModel(NestedActionAwareBuildControllerAdapter.java:31)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:131)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionAdapter.beforeTasks(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:99)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.beforeTasks(DefaultBuildTreeModelCreator.java:52)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$fromBuildModel$1(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.lambda$runBuild$4(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:106)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$5(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.doTransition(StateTransitionController.java:247)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.lambda$transition$6(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultSynchronizer.withLock(DefaultSynchronizer.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.StateTransitionController.transition(StateTransitionController.java:166)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.runBuild(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:103)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.fromBuildModel(DefaultBuildTreeLifecycleController.java:74)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:43)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.run(ProblemReportingBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:65)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:136)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:122)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(RootBuildLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:40)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.DefaultBuildTreeContext.execute(DefaultBuildTreeContext.java:40)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.execute(BuildTreeLifecycleBuildActionExecutor.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:61)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:204)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:66)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$2.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:59)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:73)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.lambda$execute$0(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.runAsWorkerThread(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:109)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.execute(RunAsWorkerThreadBuildActionExecutor.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.continuous.ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecutor.java:110)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecutor.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.DefaultBuildSessionContext.execute(DefaultBuildSessionContext.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:100)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter$ActionImpl.apply(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:88)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:69)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:62)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildSessionLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:52)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:40)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.internal.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: react-native-vision-camera: Failed to find node_modules/ path!
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.internal.classpath.Instrumented$FileInputStreamConstructorCallSite.callConstructor(Instrumented.java:971)
    at build_8xdr2t92danxkfpy7xenyym6t.findNodeModules(/Users/userName/Desktop/react-native-vision-camera/package/android/build.gradle:63)
    at build_8xdr2t92danxkfpy7xenyym6t$findNodeModules.callStatic(Unknown Source)
    at build_8xdr2t92danxkfpy7xenyym6t.run(/Users/userName/Desktop/react-native-vision-camera/package/android/build.gradle:66)
    at org.gradle.groovy.scripts.internal.DefaultScriptRunnerFactory$ScriptRunnerImpl.run(DefaultScriptRunnerFactory.java:91)
    ... 177 more
```

Comment: Remove the MaxPermSize option, it no longer exists (since Java 8).

Comment: @MarkRotteveel: I did as you say, but I get the following error:

https://pastebin.com/ZTtzH19i

File error: https://github.com/mrousavy/react-native-vision-camera/blob/main/package/android/build.gradle#L63

Comment: Would you mind if I ask you to add your system details though? Like CPU, RAM and etc.

Comment: @AmerllicA: MacBook Pro, 2 GHz Intel Core i5 quad-core, 16 GB 3733 MHz LPDDR4X. It's a new computer only a few years old.

Comment: @Paul, It seems your system resources are enough. I should check. I'll answer you later. wait, please. I'm quite busy now.